# doxygen alias with arguments: the (classical) linebr problem

Tags: warnings, alias, doxygen, line-breaks

- consider the following doxygen alias:

```
ALIASES += "sbl_add_package_main_class{4}=\addtogroup \1-ref-manual ^^ @{ ^^ \class \2 ^^ \brief \3 ^^ \4 ^^ @}"
```

or equivalently

```
ALIASES += sbl_add_package_main_class{4}="\addtogroup \1-ref-manual ^^ @{ ^^ \class \2 ^^ \brief \3 ^^ \4 ^^ @}"
```

- upon running doxygen (1.8.18) onto the following C++ code

```
  /**
       \sbl_add_package_main_class{Molecular_potential_energy, T_Phi_psi_dihedral_angles_visitor,
        Defines iterator over all successive pairs of dihedrals.,
       \details Defines iterator over all successive pairs of dihedrals.  
       \tparam CovalentStructure The type of the input covalent structure
       }
    */  
    template <class CovalentStructure>
    class T_Phi_psi_dihedral_angles_visitor
    {
      
    public:
      
      typedef T_Phi_psi_dihedral_angles_visitor<CovalentStructure> Self;
      typedef CovalentStructure                               Covalent_structure;

      static inline Iterator begin(const CovalentStructure& C);

      static inline Iterator end(const CovalentStructure& C);
      
    };//end class T_Phi_psi_dihedral_angles_visitor
```

- I get the following warning:

```
warning: the name '\_linebr' supplied as the argument of the \class, \struct, \union, or \include command is not an input file
```

which does not make any sense to me since the second argument `T_Phi_psi_dihedral_angles_visitor` is well formed.

I have tried to add/remove carriage returns, add/remove ^^ in the alias ... total failure !

any clue !?

thanks a lot, Frederic.

Comment: Tested it with 1.8.18 and 1.8.20 and in both cases I get a warning. Looks like a bug. Best is to create an issue in the doxygen issue tracker: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=report-a-bug-or-issue.md&title=

Answer (score 0):

Based on the 1.8.20 version I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 8003, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8003).

Note further:

- the `^^` between args `\3` and `\4` should not be present (will lead to warnings), the `\details` sees to it that the `\brief` is ended. These warnings are subject of further investigation.
- the physical newlines are used as well so have to be used with care.
- at the end of the `\details` line there are also 2 spaces, I don't know whether they are there intentionally or not, but (at least) 2 spaces at the end of line mean an extra new line in Markdown syntax.

**Edit**

- regarding the warnings for the `^^` between `\3` and `4` I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 8004, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8004).

**Edit September 17,2020**
The mentioned proposed patches both have been integrated in master on github

Comment: I am sorry: I think I am up to date

ecrins-fcazals> git log -n 1
commit e1d10844790b1f8386eada1ea73960b16e6bc440 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Merge: 72591fd5 fa32d44f
Author: Dimitri van Heesch <doxygen@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Sep 3 21:19:35 2020 +0200
    Merge pull request #7998 from albert-github/feature/issue_7996
    issue #7996 \ref commands broken in markdown tables 

The alias has been updated:
ALIASES += "sbl_add_package_main_class{4}=\addtogroup \1-ref-manual ^^ @{ ^^ \class \2 ^^ \brief \3 \4 ^^ @}"

But I still get the warning.

Comment: You are up to date with the master version, the mentioned pull requests are proposed pull requests by me and not yet integrated int the master version of doxygen. Either wait till  they are integrated into the master version of doxygen or apply them by hand to your version (they are small).